# gnome-system-tools: command not found

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu, network-manager

I've just installed Lubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish). I can go online only via a cable.

I looked for wifi-radar but it doesn't seem to exist for Lubuntu.

I found wifi-qr but it doesn't function :
ERROR: zbar processor in _zbar_video_open():
system error: opening video device '/dev/video0': No such file or directory (2)
(What video anyway??? I wasn't trying to watch a video.)

I tried network-manager but typing nm-applet does nothing.

Typing sudo nm-applet says
"(nm-applet:45014): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 17:11:07.459: gdk_window_thaw_toplevel_updates: assertion 'window->update_and_descendants_freeze_count > 0' failed"
and then nothing.

I installed gnome-system-tools but typing "gnome-system-tools" says "command not found". With or without "sudo" in front.

"ls /sys/class/net" only finds eth0 and lo. But this pc had wireless before this installation...

lspci :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS480/RS482/RS485 Host Bridge (rev 10)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC4xx/RS4xx PCI Bridge [int gfx]
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC4xx/RS4xx PCI Express Port 2
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC4xx/RS4xx PCI Express Port 3
00:12.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 Non-Raid-5 SATA
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI0)
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI1)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI2)
00:13.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI3)
00:13.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI4)
00:13.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB Controller (EHCI)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 14)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 IDE
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 PCI to LPC Bridge
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS482/RS485 [Radeon Xpress 1100/1150]
05:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX (rev 02)
08:01.0 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 22)
08:01.1 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C843 MMC Host Controller (rev 12)
```

What should I do, please?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Lubuntu uses LXQt, not GNOME.  What were you after ?  as there is almost nothing it will have impact on with a Lubuntu/LXQt environment which is Qt5 based and not GNOME. The package I think you installed (if using *amd64*) will install these files https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/amd64/gnome-system-tools/filelist where you may note there is no such command of that name. Sorry I don't know what you mean by WiFi radar

Comment: wifi-radar is a tool I had in Kubuntu. You could install it and then type "wifi-radar' and it displayed all the local wifi networks, along with signal strengh and requested security (if any).

Comment: Now I've got wifi functionning (explained here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1465063/i-struggled-to-get-eth1-wifi-up-and-now-it-goes-back-down-at-each-reboot) and wifi-qr functions but doesn't do much (it just lists the known wifi network). I would like a tool to display (and eventually connect to) all the wifi networks around.